# Is it possible and advisable to edit cell data in a prepareRenderer method in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, formatting, tablecellrenderer

The following is the snippet of my code:

public GUI() {
        ...

```
    deadlinesAndTimeTasksTable = new JTable(deadlinesAndTimeTasksModel) {
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            String dateTime;
            String deadline = (String) deadlinesAndTimeTasksTable.getValueAt(row, 4);
            if (!deadline.equals("- -")) {
                dateTime = deadline;
            } else {
                dateTime = (String) deadlinesAndTimeTasksTable.getValueAt(row, 3);
            }


            DateParser dp = new DateParser(dateTime);



            if (dp.getDateTimeInMilliseconds() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                String description = (String) deadlinesAndTimeTasksTable.getValueAt(row, 1) + "!!";
                setValueAt(description, row, 1)
                c.setForeground(Color.RED);

            } else {
                c.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            }

            String status = (String) deadlinesAndTimeTasksTable.getValueAt(row, 5);

            if (status.equals("undone")) {

                c.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                c.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12 ));
            } else {
                c.setBackground(new Color(0,180,150,30));


            }




            return c;
        }

    };

 ...
}
```

What I want to do is to append a character, say "!!" to one of my cell that is storing the description of the task if the time of the task is earlier than the current time. However, if I use setValueAt(description + "!!", row, 1) (1 is the column storing the description), what will happen is that this method will keep being called over and over again and "!!" keeps getting appended such that I have "!!!!!........", causing my program to crash in the end.

Can I know what is causing the problem and how I can solve it?

The other question is should prepareRenderer only be used to change the format of the data such that editing cell data in prepareRenderer is not advisable?

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I use setValueAt...

Don't use setValueAt(...), this will update the TableModel as you have noticed.

The default renderer is a JLabel so instead you can do something like:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)c;
label.setText(...);
```

This will only affect the current rendering, not the TableModel.

> prepareRenderer only be used to change the format of the data

Normally you would use a custom renderer to format the data. This is how an Integer of value "123456789" is formatted to "123,456,789" or how a date is formatted to YYYY-MM-DD.

The only time I use the prepare renderer method is for row level highlighting. See [Table Row Renderering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information.